# ASP.NET MVC and Excel-Like Grid Control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spreadsheet

I have looked at Spire, Spreadsheet Gear, and GrapeCity (as well as just web-search-engines) to find a grid-like control that will allow local data manipulation that looks/feels like Excel and Access. In particular is the need for a "fill handle", so a set of 50,000 items can be edited in one box and then a user can change columns below it, simply.

Can anyone recommend something? Silverlight or Flash is fine also if HTML5 or classic JS is unavailable.

This requirement for a fill handle is a killer....

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a try using [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/). Using Html and  jquery its giving better results.

Try [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) also.